# How to align a div which contains many divs to align in the center

Tags: html, css, alignment

I am trying to align all blocks of foo to the horizontal center of the webpage.

See my code below-

```
<div id="cert" style="display:block; align:center;">
  <div class="foo" style="background-color:violet;"></div>
  <div class="foo" style="background-color:indigo;"></div>
  <div class="foo" style="background-color:blue;"></div>
  <div class="foo" style="background-color:green;"></div>
  <div class="foo" style="background-color:yellow;"></div>
  <div class="foo" style="background-color:orange;"></div>
  <div class="foo" style="background-color:red;"></div>
  <div class="foo" style="background-color:silver;"></div>
</div>
```

class foo

```
.foo {
float: left;
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
margin: 5px;
border-width: 1px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Hello, I suggest you learn http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/ to know the standards on arranging your HTML and CSS

Comment: @RexAdrivan - Including an entire framework is total overkill for something as basic as this. The OP would do better to learn the basics before relying on Bootstrap.

Comment: by horizontal center, do you mean middle of the of the monitor or each div is centered in #cert?

Comment: It might help if you post a picture of exactly what you're looking for so we can make sure we're answering the right question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to have all your divs in one line horizontally, then use this:

```css
.foo {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 5px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    border-radius: 5px;
    display:inline-block;
}
#cert {
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div id="cert" style="display:block; align:center;">
    <div class="foo" style="background-color:violet;"></div>
    <div class="foo" style="background-color:indigo;"></div>
    <div class="foo" style="background-color:blue;"></div>
    <div class="foo" style="background-color:green;"></div>
    <div class="foo" style="background-color:yellow;"></div>
    <div class="foo" style="background-color:orange;"></div>
    <div class="foo" style="background-color:red;"></div>
    <div class="foo" style="background-color:silver;"></div>
</div>
```

Use `text-align:center` on the parent div to center it's contents, then remove the `float:left` on the children and instead use `display:inline-block`.

Answer (score 1):

remove `float: left;` from your css and add `margin: 5px auto`, and that should horizontally center your `<div>` elements.  `float: left` will always push your content to the left.

**Edit**: You can also remove the `style="..."` block from your outer `<div>` as it doesn't really do anything. `<div>` elements display block by default, and `align` by itself isn't a valid css property (although `text-align` is).

**Edit 2:** If you want the outer `<div>` to be centered, but the inner `<div>` elements to show one after another, just set a `width` and `margin` on your outer `<div>`:

```
#cert {
    width: 500px; /* or whatever you want */
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

If you want your inner `<div>` elements to be centered individually (instead of being left-aligned within a centered block), then you'll want to go with the other answers (i.e. set the outer `<div>` to `text-align: center;` and the inner `<div>` elements to `display: inline-block;`)

Good luck learning CSS.  It's a fun world.

Comment: But this will change them from all being on the same horizontal line to appearing one under the other vertically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this hack, if you don't mind to set your inner divs as inline-block you can 
Try this:

```
 #cert {
 width: 80%;
 margin: 1% auto;
 text-align: center;
 }

 #cert .foo {
  display: inline-block;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you mean something like this, here the foo elements are vertically center aligned, see codepen example

> http://codepen.io/Edrees21/pen/bNObqm

```
<div id="cert">
  <div class="foo" style="background-color:violet;"></div>
  <div class="foo" style="background-color:indigo;"></div>
  <div class="foo" style="background-color:blue;"></div>
  <div class="foo" style="background-color:green;"></div>
  <div class="foo" style="background-color:yellow;"></div>
  <div class="foo" style="background-color:orange;"></div>
  <div class="foo" style="background-color:red;"></div>
  <div class="foo" style="background-color:silver;"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
}
#cert {
    height: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.foo {
    float: left;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 5px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```